# List all pages using a specific template on a page

Tags: templates, blog, list

I just created a WordPress page called *Latest Blog Posts* where I want to list, in chronological order, all pages from my website using the template name **"Blog"**. The list should contain the title of the pages, the date the pages were published and their thumbnail images.

Is there any WordPress built-in function/query that could easily allow me to do so? If not, how should I proceed when creating new blog pages (using the template **"Blog"**) to allow me to list them all on a single page.

Most of my pages do not use the template name **"Blog"** but I recently decided to ad a blog section to my website and would love to be able to list all my blog posts on a single page.

Comment: Use [`get_pages`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages)

Comment: Is there a reason you're using pages for this and not posts? Posts are intended for a date-based blog structure, pages are not.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom post type called blog. This would group all your "blog" posts together. Once you have that done, create a template file called archive-blog.php, this will be the file that you can use to list all your posts under the "blog" custom post type. For a single post view, the template would be single-blog.php.

These files would reside under the parent directory of your theme (or child theme if you're using a child theme).